# How to get GPG public key in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to get the public key ID from GPG.  Everything on SO discusses importing, exporting, etc.  In the example below, I need to get the `ABCD1234` value to use in a bash script?

```
$ gpg --list-keys  
/Users/jblow/.gnupg/pubring.gpg  
---------------------------------  
pub   2048R/ABCD1234 2016-09-20
uid       [ultimate] Joe Blow <joe.blow@nowhere.com>
sub   2048R/JDKKHU76 2016-09-20
```

Comment: From `man gpg`: "Avoid  using  the  output  of  this command in scripts or other programs as it is likely to change as GnuPG changes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` + `bash` string manipulation way of doing it.

```
# 'awk' extracts the '2048R/ABCD1234' part of the command and
# string-manipulation done to strip-off characters up to the trailing '/' character

$ keyVal=$(gpg --list-keys | awk '/pub/{if (length($2) > 0) print $2}'); echo "${keyVal##*/}"
ABCD1234
```

If you want to extract the key for the `sub` just change the pattern in `awk` to

```
$ keyVal=$(gpg --list-keys | awk '/sub/{if (length($2) > 0) print $2}'); echo "${keyVal##*/}"
JDKKHU76
```

Comment: keyVal=$(gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG | awk '/sec/{if (length($2) > 0) print $2}'); echo "${keyVal##*/}"

Comment: This actually works perfect, thank you for the help! I added a little tweak so I can use it to get signatures for AWS, so I can verify them. `keyVal=$(gpg --list-signatures | grep sig | awk '/Amazon/{if (length($2) > 0) print $3}'); echo "${keyVal##*/}"`

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same requirement today (extracting the key ID in order to use it together with duplicity in a bash script).

In the man page of gpg I read:

> For **scripted** or other unattended use of gpg make sure to use the
> machine-parseable  interface  and
> not the default interface which is intended for direct use by humans.  The machine-parseable inter-
> face provides a stable and well documented API independent of the locale or future changes of  gpg.
> To enable this interface use the options **--with-colons** and --status-fd.  For certain operations the
> option --command-fd may come handy too.  See this man page and the file `DETAILS' for the  specifi-
> cation  of  the  interface.

I managed to extract the key ID I wanted by doing:

```sh
gpg --list-signatures --with-colons | grep 'sig' | grep 'the Name-Real of my key' | head -n 1 | cut -d':' -f5
```

PS: https://devhints.io/gnupg helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep:

```
gpg --list-keys | grep pub | grep -o -P '(?<=/)[A-Z0-9]{8}'
```

Output:

```
ABCD1234
```

Comment: Think this cleaner, but both this and the accepted answer work just fine